# Character Table of $C_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, characters

$$\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
 & 1 & g & g^2 & g^3 & g^4 & g^5\\
\phi_0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\phi_1 & 1 & \zeta_6^1 &  &  &  &   \\
\phi_2 & 1 & \zeta_6^2 &  &  &  &   \\
\phi_3 & 1 & \zeta_6^3 &  &  &  &   \\
\phi_3 & 1 & \zeta_6^4 &  &  &  &   \\
\phi_5 & 1 & \zeta_6^5 &  &  &  &   \end{array}$$

I'm trying to construct a character table for $C_6$, with generator $g$. Since $\phi_0$ is the trivial character, $\phi_0(g^n)$ for $1=<n=<5$ is 1. Similarly, since 1 is the identity element, any character $\phi_n(1)$ = 1. I also know that each character of $C_6$ will send the generator $g$ to a different $n^{th}$ root of unity.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. In general, how do I make the character table of a cyclic group? I'm assuming I need to use the 6th root of unity, $e^{2\pi i\over 6}$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C_{6}$ is a cyclic group then $\phi_1: 1\rightarrow e^{2\pi i\over 6}$
$\phi_i=(\phi_1)^i$ $i=1....5$\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
 & 1 & g & g^2 & g^3 & g^4 & g^5\\
\phi_0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\phi_1 & 1 & \zeta_6 & \zeta_6^2 & \zeta_6^3 &\zeta_6^4 &\zeta_6^5  &   \\
\phi_2 & 1& \zeta_6^2 & \zeta_6^4 & 1 &\zeta_6^2 &\zeta_6^4  &  \\
\phi_3 & 1 & \zeta_6^3 & 1 & \zeta_6^3 &1 &\zeta_6^3  & \\
\phi_4 & 1 & \zeta_6^4 & \zeta_6^2 & 1 &\zeta_6^4 &\zeta_6^2  & \\
\phi_5 & 1 & \zeta_6^5 & \zeta_6^4 & \zeta_6^3 &\zeta_6^2&\zeta_6  &   \end{array}

Call $e^{2\pi i\over 6}=\zeta_6$

Comment: Thanks mcmat23. For example, $\phi_2(g^2)$ = $\phi_1^i(g)^2$? How does this computation lead to $\zeta_6^3$?

Comment: sorry,I miscalculated!!!

Comment: Oops, I meant to ask how you did any of those computations! I just happened to chance upon an incorrect one. :P Could you explain?

Comment: You must calculate the exponents   mod 6 because $\zeta_6^6=1$